# N+1 issue for custom method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select-n-plus-1

in my rails app I have a `User` model with a method called `price_tier`:

```
def price_tier
  Spree::PriceTier.by_code[read_attribute(:price_tier)]
end
```

However, when I have a collection of `@users` and call the price_tier one by one, it will load `PriceTier` query for every instance, which causes a N+1 issue.

`includes` is not working here since it's not an association.

```
@users.map { |user| user.price_tier }
```

Is there any way to modify the code which fixing the N+1 issue?

Comment: how are user and price_tier related ?

Comment: @Subash It will search the `price_tier` by the code. `user.price_tier == price_tier.code`. But don't have association like `has_many`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You really should setup the relationship between the models directly, e.g. `user has_one :price_tier`. This will make the code here a breeze.

If you don't do this, you're jumping through hoops for something that should be straightforward. You could *maybe* use something like the following, though it will still be far less effient than a direct relationship:

```
tiers = Spree::PriceTier.where(code: @users.pluck(:price_tier))
                        .each_with_object({}) { |tier, hash| hash[tier[code]] = tier }

@users.map { |user| tiers[user.price_tier] }
```

N.B. the above assumes removing the instance method `:price_tier` and using the attribute.

I'm not sure it's really worth including the above - you collect the users' price_tier, hit the db (only once, rather than for every user) for the tiers, iterate through them all to create a hash for fast access, *then* iterate through the users to map these. That's a lot of work for something that's solved easily by setting up a relationship.

Hope that helps, and really hope the tone comes across OK in the above - basically mean you *could* do something like the above, though the real advice would be: please don't, setup a relationship and work with the conventional approach here :)

Comment: Did this help at all @Stephen?